# C++ map::iterator vs map.find() iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

What is the difference between an iterator in a range-based `for` loop, and an iterator returned by the map's `find()` method?

In other words, what I want to know is:

To access map elements, why do we use the `.` as well as the `->` operator with an iterator to the same container? i.e.

```
map<int, int> m;

// method 1: accessing element using range-based for loop iterator
// use of dot operator to access elements
for (auto i : m)    
  cout << i.first << " " << i.second << endl;      

// method 2: accessing element using begin/end for loop iterator
// use of arrow operator to access elements
for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
  cout << i->first << " " << i->second << endl;
```

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: An iterator models a pointer.

Comment: `for (auto i : m)....` here `i` is not an iterator but a [`std::map::value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) .  The [ranged for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) internally uses iterators but you get the values pointed to by the iterator.

Comment: `for (auto i : m)....` here, `i` is a **copy** of each map entry.  `i.first` and `i.second` are not the _map's elements_, they are copies of what is in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misconception. In the [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) the `i` is:

> range-declaration  -   a declaration of a named variable, whose type is the type of the element of the sequence represented by range-expression, or a reference to that type. Often uses the auto specifier for automatic type deduction

In your case, the first `i` is what is in the map, so `std::pair<const int, int>` whereas the second `i` is the return type of `m.begin()` which is the `std::map<int, int>::iterator`. For a more in depth view, you can look at the live example on [cpp insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/a3d6dc5a).

That is why one uses `.` (because it is a copy of the **value** in the map) and the other uses `->` (because it is an iterator).

Fun tip, as of c++17, you can use:

```
for (const auto& [key, value]: m) {
   // use the key and the value seperatly
   ...
```

Which is much nicer.

Comment: "*the first `i` is what is in the map, so `std::pair<int, int>`*" - technically, it is `std::pair<const int, int>`, since map keys are constants.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right, the insights link is so cool, because it shows you *everything...*

Answer (score 2):

A [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) uses iterators internally, but it does not expose those iterators to you.

So, in your first method, `i` is not an iterator at all, rather it receives each `std::pair` in the `std::map` when each loop iteration internally dereferences the current iterator.  So, `auto i` is deduced as `std::pair<const int, int> i`, and thus you can use `i.first` etc to access the members of that `std::pair`.

Whereas in your second method, `m.begin()` returns an iterator. So, `auto i` is deduced as `std::map<int, int>::iterator i`, and thus you have to use `i->first` (or `(*i).first`) etc to manually dereference that iterator on each loop iteration in order to access the members of the `std::pair` that it refers to.

This is why `i` is not a good name for your loop variables.  Use more meaningful names instead, eg:

```cpp
for (auto& elem : m)    
  cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << endl;      

for (auto iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); ++iter)
  cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second << endl;
```

Comment: I like it: "This is why i is not a good name for your loop variable. Use more meaningful names....
for (auto& elem : m) ...
iter->first " 
That's good programming practice.